# How to add version to all style and JS tags(includes) inside Views in Codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Whenever I release a new version of the website to the clients, I have to instruct them to clear their browser cache so that they see the updates.

Now, after searching I found that I have to add versions to style and Js files before releasing the new version so that my client's browser will detect revision and fetch the latest css/js resources. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367541/how-to-clear-my-clients-cache-next-time-they-log-in)

Example:

<script type="text/javascript" src="**include/232/init.js**"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="**include/init.js?232**"></script>

Where 232 is your modifiable version number that should be changed whenever you release new code.

After updating the versions, things are working fine. But I do not want to open up all the views and update the versions manually. 
Instead I am searching for some logic which will update/set a new version to the Style / Javascript tags inside all the Views located in Views Directory.

Is there a way to do that ??

Comment: This concept is known as "Cache Busting". Not having knowledge of the codeigniter ecosystem, all I found was this: https://github.com/Wixel/CodeIgniter-AssetLoader

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `version` like `setting` in your `config.php` file:

```
$config['curr_ver'] = "1.5";
```

Then in your files, you can write them this way:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="include/init.js?v=<?=$this->config->item("curr_ver");?>"></script>
```

That should render:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/init.js?v=1.5"></script>
```

> This should be a just one time refactoring job, and when you need to change to a new version, you just update the setting in the `config.php` file to `1.6` or another value.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a version in your `config/constants.php` file as a constant:

```
define("UPDATE_VERSION", "2");
```

Then you can add this line to your script and style files:

```
<script src="include/init.js?v=<?= UPDATE_VERSION ?>"></script>init
```